# Modify css generated from scss in a plugin in a container created with docker-compose

Tags: css, docker, sass, docker-compose

In my docker-compose.yml I define a service for grafana:

```
grafana:
  container_name: grafana
  image: grafana/grafana:latest
  restart: always
  volumes:
    - ./grafana/config.ini:/etc/grafana/grafana.ini # config
    - /var/lib/grafana:/var/lib/grafana # data
    - /var/log/grafana:/var/log/grafana # logs
    - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
  environment:
    - GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS=<plugin>
```

The last line installs a plugin within the container and its .scss file is at `/var/lib/grafana/plugins/<plugin>/src/css/diagram.scss`

After running `docker-compose up` I can inject text into `diagram.scss` by running

```
docker exec -it grafana sh -c "echo '<my_style>' >> /var/lib/grafana/plugins/.../diagram.scss"`
```

How can I set up a watch or whatever within this container so that changing this scss file actually updates the rendered css?

Bonus: It would also be great to actually use

`command: bash -c "echo 'custom_style' >> /var/lib/grafana/plugins/...`

in the docker-compose file to avoid the extra step after building the container, but after trying all the different Docker and yml syntax suggestions I've found, I just can't seem to make that work.

Comment: I would just mount the plugin directory as a volume, install compass, and keep a terminal open with the `compass watch` command running on the directory. If you want to go the extra mile you could create a new docker image from the grafana image, install compass locally, then setup something like supervisord to start the processes.

Comment: It looks like he is already mounting `/var/lib/grafana` as a volume (all directories under that will be shared as well).